# What throws Internet Explorer into quirks mode?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, xhtml, w3c-validation, quirks-mode

I have created a webpage (**http://www.snow4life.yum.pl**) that was rendered properly in firefox, chrome etc. Of course dumb IE complicated things, because it enters quirk mode automatically, even though doctype is properly set and site goes through [w3 validation](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsnow4life.yum.pl%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&st=1&user-agent=W3C_Validator%2F1.1) (there is one error of missing some char, but file was cleared in hex editor). How can I stop ie from entering quirks mode ? Is there any way ?

Answer (score 27):

Try killing all the whitespace before the DOCTYPE.

EDIT: There is an `<feff>` character which is a Unicode BOM signature at the start of the file. Since you may not have a text editor that can actually see that, try deleting the entire first line and paste over it with

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

And do NOT save the file with a BOM unicode signature. If this doesn't work, try a different text editor altogether.

Comment: Your site is in quirks mode in Firefox, too. There still is a whitespace in front of the doctype.

Comment: damn it no matter what I paste there, ie still in quirks mode. Even with copied/pasted templates from w3c. wtf

Comment: the best part : I've saved main page of w3c.org and renamed it as my template. W3C validator shows 40 errors !! And of course - quirks mode.

Comment: I'm using vim now, clear templates from w3c and still the same. I'm just pasting the code to vim -> save'as -> base.html and then send it to server. That's all. Still w3c validator shows this stupid "Start tag expected, '<' not found" :/

Comment: okay I've placed it on different server and it works now. Can server somehow influence it ?

Comment: Are you using flat html or a template/CMS? What server?

Comment: i'm using it as a django template but currently there are no django specific tags, only pure html.

Answer (score 7):

Paste the below code within the head tag

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

Answer (score 6):

Quirks mode in any version of IE will also be triggered if anything precedes the DOCTYPE. 
For example, if a hypertext document contains a comment, space or any tag before the DOCTYPE declaration, IE will use quirks mode:

```
<!-- This comment will put IE 6, 7, 8, and 9 in quirks mode -->
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

Answer (score 3):

I added both the doctype from the first comment and then the meta tag and it worked thanks guys .... and no thanks to IE :(

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

and

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```

I have just changed the doctype to html5 and it still works great

```
 <!DOCTYPE html> 
    <html>
      <head> 
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```