# Html page edited by the server after upload?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, doctype, quirks-mode

It's a continuation of this post : [What throws Internet Explorer into quirks mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3949941/what-throws-internet-explorer-into-quirks-mode) .

I have a webpage, built on Django LFC CMS ( **http://snow4life.pl/** ). Problem is that when I upload my files to server, the default templates (**http://bitbucket.org/diefenbach/lfc-theme-1.0/src/tip/lfc_theme/templates/lfc/base.html**) are somehow edited by the server and some random whitespaces are added before the DOCTYPE declaration. The declaration itself is moved somewhere in the `<body>` segment. This of course throws internet explorer into quirks mode. This is not the templates fault, as on the demo page it is working normally ( **http://demo.django-lfc.com/**). Do you have any ideas what can cause this ? I've tried uploading empty html pages, samples from w3c, editing it in hex mode and nothing works.

---

**EDIT**

I'm uploading via WinSCP. Here are the screenshots from edits in vi on server, winscp's editor on server, vim on my local disk and vi(hex) locally.

[image]

Comment: How are you uploading them? (Sorry, I don't know Django LFC CMS at all.) Do the files look modified when you inspect them directly (grab FTP copies, or ssh in), or only when you fetch them through a browser?

Comment: I don't know how Python works, would white space in included code files be reflected in the output, or are .py files always pure code? (Asking the Python people here.) Also @mat you should add the  appropriate Python/Django tags, this is probably not a HTML problem

Comment: I'm using the same includes as in the demo, so why should they add some whitespaces here ?

Comment: also uploading it to my ftp (without the imports at the beginning) renders it in IE7 mode and not quirks. http://wymiana.phugaja.pl/base.html . Still on the server I'm uploading the files, I have some other django projects and they're working properly. the hell ? :/

Comment: did you try saving the file in ASCII mode?  I know some UTF-8 format has some special character at the beginning of the file (Notepad++ lets you choose).  You can't go onto the server to edit the file?

Comment: just noticed, that when I'm on /login page, which uses the same base template - everything works fine. It's really giving me a headache now.

Comment: Make sure you upload in BIN not ASC mode in your FTP client.

Comment: checked. Also checked saving in ascii. Still the same. Why on earth two pages, inheriting from the same template are rendered in different way ? Even if scraped down to this base template only.

Answer (score 0):

You can always force ie to run in standards mode :

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />`