# No way around Quirks mode in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, compatibility, quirks-mode, blackboard

I'm writing a page for a Blackboard course and compatibility mode is rendering it useless.
Blackboard uses iFrames to embed content so every page I create is essentially embedded using an iFrame. I've tried the following at the top of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```

with no success. The page has custom elements and a drag and drop. I was able to get the custom elements to show with the following:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script>
document.createElement("term");
document.createElement("r");
document.createElement("wr");
</script>
<![endif]-->
```

but the content will not drag.
Here is my drag+drop code:

```
<table id="terms_container" frame="box" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" >
  <tr ><td style="text-align:center;">Drag each of these items to the correct bin.</td></tr>
  <tr><td class="box"><hr>

    <term id="drag1" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">
    float salesTax = .05f;</term>
    <term id="drag2" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">char ampersand  '&';</term>
    <term id="drag3" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">final Max_Players = 4;</term>
    <term id="drag4" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">final int MAX_PLAYERS = 10;</term>

    <term id="drag5" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">String literal: "Hello World!</term>
    <term id="drag6" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">char diamond = Cx74;</term>
    <term id="drag7" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">float weight = 124.3;</term>

    <term id="drag8" draggable="true" ondragstart="drag(event)">long worldPopulation = +6000000000L;</term>


    </td></tr>
</table>
<div id="venn">
  <div id="c1" class="circle">
    <p>Valid</p>
    <div id="collection" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="ans1"></div>
  </div>

  <div id="c2" class="circle" >
    <p>Not Valid</p>
    <div id="collection" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)" class="ans2"></div>
  </div>

</div>
        </div>
    </div>


<script type="Text/javascript">
 var count = 0;
function allowDrop(ev){
ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev)
{
ev.dataTransfer.setData("Text",ev.target.id);
} 

function drop(ev)
{
ev.preventDefault();
var thetag = ev.target.nodeName;
var theanswer = ev.target.className;
var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
  if(thetag == "TERM"){
    null;
  }
  else{
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
    checkAnswer(data, theanswer);
  }

}

function checkAnswer(theterm, theiranswer){
  var stripped = theterm.replace('drag', '');
  var _0xc89b=["","\x62\x6F\x74\x68","\x61\x6E\x73\x31","\x61\x6E\x73\x32"];var theanswers=[_0xc89b[0],_0xc89b[2],_0xc89b[2],_0xc89b[3],_0xc89b[2],_0xc89b[3],_0xc89b[3],_0xc89b[3],_0xc89b[2]];
  if(theiranswer == theanswers[stripped]){
    count++;
    $("#"+theterm+" wr").remove();
    $('#'+theterm).append(" <r>&#x2713;</r>");
    $('#'+theterm).css( 'cursor', 'default' );
    $("#"+theterm).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this ).html( $( event.originalTarget ).html() );
        $( ui.draggable ).draggable( "destroy" );
      }
    });
    $('#'+theterm).on('dragstart', function(event) { event.preventDefault(); });
  }
  else if(theiranswer=="box"){
    null;
  }
  else{
    $("#"+theterm+" wr").remove();
    $('#'+theterm).append(" <wr>&#x2717;</wr>");
  }
  if(count==8){
    $('.box').html("<h3 style=\"text-align: center;\">Correct!</h3>");
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
    if(isFirefox==true){
      $('#replay').css( "display", "block");
      $('#replay').css("margin-top", "200px");
      $('#replay').css("margin-left", "44%");
    }
    else{
      $('#win').css( "display", "block");
      restartbutton();
    }
  }
}

function restartbutton(){
  setTimeout(function() {
    //$('#win').hide();
    $('#replay').css( "display", "block");
  },2000);
}


function restartgame(){
  alert("This button will restart the game");
  //window.location.reload();
}
</script>
```

Comment: Use `<!DOCTYPE html>` instead of the transitional doctype. And don't set the `x-ua-compat` to IE8. If you're going to set it, set it to the latest version of IE on the market (presently 11).

Comment: +1 because I feel bad for you :( Why, blackboard!?

Comment: @JonathanSampson I've tried that. It might take it off the quirks mode, but the items are still not draggable. statue more like why IE!? IE is a crime against humanity.

Comment: @pedrumgolriz IE is actually a really great browser, you just have to carefully build your sites to work properly. Your question title suggests Quirks Mode is the problem; if that is no longer the issue, we can solve your drag/drop issue.

Comment: @JonathanSampson I'm not completely sure if the quirks problem is solved. Only in the iFrame does the site not work. When I open the page outside of the iFrame, it works perfectly.

Comment: New information on this, when I click the refresh button a couple times really quickly, the content loads as it should. Whats up with that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Page loading in Quirks mode in Internet Explorer - doctype commented out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14488284/page-loading-in-quirks-mode-in-internet-explorer-doctype-commented-out)

Comment: I know this is an old question, but did you try setting it to 'IE=Edge' ?